# What is the word for not showing your own opinion while informing someone about a subject

Tags: single-word-requests

For example: Informing someone about the government shutdown without revealing your own opinion about the shutdown.

I wanted to stay ... so I don't influence your opinion.

The word I'm thinking of is not objective but it has somewhat of a similar meaning.

Comment: "neutral", perhaps?

Comment: Also maybe "impartial".

Answer (score 1):

*unbiased*

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unbiased

I wanted to stay *unbiased* so I don't influence your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

***evenhanded***

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evenhanded)

"The President gave her evenhanded account of what really happened at the meeting."

Answer (score 0):

- I want to stay **uncoloured,** so as to not influence your opinion.

**uncoloured** (BrE) **uncolored** (AmE)  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/uncoloured)

> not influenced or biased

**uncolored**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/210533?redirectedFrom=uncolored#eid)

> not invested with any specious or deceptive appearance or quality;
>   open, undisguised; not influenced or affected by something.

As in:

> Those evaluators, known as master educators, were meant to offer an
>   outsiders’ dispassionate view of the teachers’ work, **uncolored** by
>   favoritism or personality clashes. Washington Post Feb 9, 2016